# NMAP Scan Returns Odd OS Detection

Tags: linux, operating-systems, nmap, network-scanners

I am new to NMAP but I was using it to troubleshoot some issues I have been having. I ran a scan on a device and I know the device runs some sort of Linux or Ubuntu OS and I was attempting to figure out what that OS was exactly.

When I ran the scan the OS details were as follows:

```
Device type: printer
Running: HP embedded
OS CPE: cpe:/h:hp:laserjet_cp4525 cpe:/h:hp:laserjet_m451dn
OS details: HP LaserJet M451dn, CM1415fnw, or CP4525
```

I am 100% certain that this device is not a printer, nor does it have any printer functions as far as I am aware.

Why would NMAP return this information to me?

Comment: we need way more data from the scan to help - like the OS fingerprint

Comment: It's very likely that there wasn't enough info and the guess is wrong.

Comment: under the OS details is a field called TCP/IP fingerprint: but I do not have an OS fingerprint:

Comment: when posting questions about nmap, please include the full nmap command you used. I suspect that you need to increase the verbosity: `-vv`

Comment: We definitely need more information about the original nmap options used, and further details from the nmap output. Also, it would be helpful to know what the device actually is - if you're "100% certain that this device *is not* a printer" then you must have some amount of certainty about what it *is*.

Comment: When Nmap performs OS detection against a target and fails to find a perfect match, it usually repeats the attempt. By default, Nmap tries five times if conditions are favorable for OS fingerprint submission, and twice when conditions aren't so good. Specifying a lower --max-os-tries value (such as 1) speeds Nmap up, though you miss out on retries which could potentially identify the OS. Alternatively, a high value may be set to allow even more retries when conditions are favorable. This is rare, except to generate better fingerprints for submission and integration into the Nmap OS database.

Comment: https://nmap.org/book/man-os-detection.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the nmap [documentation](http://nmap.org/book/osdetect-fingerprint-format.html):

> Another cause of duplicate fingerprints is embedded devices which
>   share a common OS. For example, a **printer** from one vendor and an
>   ethernet **switch** from another may actually share an embedded OS from a
>   third vendor. In many cases, subtle differences between the devices
>   still allow them to be distinguished. But sometimes Nmap must simply
>   list a group of possibilities such as Cisco 1200-series WAP, HP
>   ProCurve 2650 switch, or Xerox Phaser 7400N or 8550DT printer.

So, it is possible that the target runs an embedded OS similar to the HP models listed in your scan.

Comment: This seems consistent, since all the known devices scanned result in this particular OS showing up. Are you aware of the OS that the HP printers above run?

Comment: Nmap reads responses bit by bit. If results are not favorable, it will retry 2 times by default. When conditions are favorable, it will try more times. The output is based on a "best guess" percentage. This can explain why you have many OS fingerprints in your output.

You can use the "--max-os-tries n" to set the max retry limit if you believe the default retry limit is less than you want.

Comment: nmap prints OS detection results based on favorable or unfavorable conditions. These conditions are not 100% accurate nor are they guaranteed. Which means that OS detection results are percentile based. If there are bites that are similar to multiple different OS's, nmap will return multiple possible OS guesses.

Comment: My comments are agreeing, yet explaining in more detail, one of the last lines in your answer.

""Nmap must simply list a group of possibilities""